# «Это красочное издание почти фолиант...» — пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

Ставится ли знак препинания в этом предложении?

**Это красочное издание почти фолиант...**

Comment: Что означает многоточие в конце Вашего предложения? Если Вы привели предложение не полностью, тогда ответы, скорее всего, Вам не помогут или даже помешают.

Comment: @Татьяна Хотелось бы видеть "обрамление" предложения. Без контекста однозначно на Ваш вопрос ответить невозможно. Тут пунктуационных вариантов — тьма.

Answer (score 3):

> *Это красочное издание почти фолиант...*

В данном предложении между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит сравнительный союз ***почти***. Запятая не нужна. Но если мы хотим особо подчеркнуть размер этого издания, интонационно выделить его, то можно поставить тире:

*Это красочное издание — почти фолиант...*

Вот что у [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92):

> Между подлежащим и сказуемым обычно тире **не ставится**:
>
> 2) если в роли связки выступают сравнительные союзы ***как, будто,
>   словно, точно, вроде как, всё равно что*** и т. п.: *Речи как
>   речи* (Фурм.); *Звёзды будто мелкие алмазы; Облака словно сказочные
>   чудовища; Сегодня небо точно море*.
>
> Отступления от этого положения у писателей-классиков и у современных
>   авторов связаны с прежними пунктуационными нормами или с желанием
>   **подчеркнуть** оттенок сравнения, содержащийся в сказуемом: *Твои речи — будто острый нож* (Л.); *Такая фраза — всё равно
>   что большой шлем в ералаше* (Т.); *Эта девушка — как
>   праздник!* (Аж.); *Срок войны — что жизни век* (Тв.).

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Знак можно не ставить.

Розенталь:
Тире обычно не ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженными существительными в именительном падеже, если сказуемое присоединяется при помощи сравнительных союзов *как, словно, будто, точно, что, вроде как, все равно как, все равно что и др.*, например:
*Сегодня небо как море.

Огни фонарей словно маяки.

Настоящие ученые что альпинисты: добираются до самых неприступных мест.

Лошади что драконы крылатые.

Пионерская песня что хорошая запевка.

Твои глаза точно звезды.*
*Вечер как вечер* (Фурманов).
*У тебя брошка вроде как пчелка* (Чехов).
*Льды как льды, пустыни как пустыни* (Каверин).
*Право, у вас душа человеческая все равно что пареная репа* (Гоголь).

*Это красочное издание почти (как) фолиант.*

Answer (score 1):

Если это полное предложение, то можно поставить тире:

> Это красочное издание — почти фолиант...

но **чаще** при наличие слов "почти" и "как" в подобных фразах знак вообще **не ставят**.

Если же предложение в вопросе приведено не целиком, то многое определит контекст. Скорее всего, это будет пунтакционно обозначенное уточнение:

> Это красочное издание — почти фолиант — мне очень понравилось
>
> Это красочное издание, почти фолиант,  мне очень понравилось
>
> Это красочное издание (почти фолиант) мне очень понравилось